# Stop LESS compiling a certain part of css

Tags: css, less

As a fix to Firefox 30 removing the ability to style a select menu's dropdown arrows, I've implemented [this workaround](http://jsbin.com/dixulavo/1/edit), but LESS won't compile it (unless I use --force, which I can't in this instance).

Using e or ~ syntax doesn't work. Is there any way to make LESS not compile a certain piece of code in a less file, and just have it stick it out as

```
:-moz-any(.select):before {
    background-color: #fff;pointer-events: none;z-index: 1;
}
```

This is the error:

> > > Expected RPAREN at line 9, col 58150. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors) Warning: Task "csslint:guar"
> > >       failed. Use --force to continue.

Comment: I suppose you could drop it in a separate CSS file.

Comment: Tried doing that and going @import in the less file but it still wouldn't work? It said use <link> instead...

Comment: What version of LESS are you using? That rule worked fine for me on the most recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a warning from csslint on your compiled output - LESS is perfectly compiling this. Csslint will always warn about this. It currently has no way to ignore specific code blocks from lint.

Answer (score 2):

CSSLint rules can be ignored if you include `csslint ignore` comments:

```
/* csslint ignore:start */
@import('normalize.css');
/* csslint ignore:end */

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Ignoring-parts-of-CSS-during-linting